# The element type '{0}' can't be assigned to the list type '{1}' flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, widget

I've been trying to follow a flutter course on udemy and in the code it gives me this error:

> The element type 'Question' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'.

here's the code in main.dart:

```
    class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int _qIndex = 0;

  void _ansQ() {
    setState(() {
      _qIndex++;
    });
    print('Answer Chosen');
  

   print(_qIndex);   }
 
   @override   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     var questions = [
       'What\'s your favorite food?',
       'What\'s your favorite color?'
     ];
     return MaterialApp(
       home: Scaffold(
           appBar: AppBar(
             title: Text('My First Flutter App'),
           ),
           body: Column(
             children: [
               Question(questions[_qIndex]), //This is the line that gives me the error
               RaisedButton(child: Text('Answer 1'), onPressed: _ansQ),
               RaisedButton(
                 child: Text('Answer 2'),
                 onPressed: () => print('Answer 2 chosen')),
               RaisedButton(child: Text('Answer 3'), onPressed: _ansQ)
             ]
           )
        ),
     );   } }
```

And here is the code in the question.dart:

```
import 'package:/flutter/material.dart';

class Question extends StatelessWidget {
  final String questionText;
  const Question(this.questionText);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(questionText);
  }
}
```

If so can you please help me?

Comment: Upgrade your flutter version, it doesn't give me the error.

Comment: The `import` line in `question.dart` has an extraneous `/`.  Make sure you fix all errors in `question.dart` before focusing on erros in files that depend on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to ad `as qus` after the import like this

```
import 'package:'PATH'/Question.dart' as qus;
```

then use

```
Column(
             children: [
              qus.Question(questions[_qIndex]), //This is the line that gives me the error
               RaisedButton(child: Text('Answer 1'), onPressed: _ansQ),
               RaisedButton(
                 child: Text('Answer 2'),
                 onPressed: () => print('Answer 2 chosen')),
               RaisedButton(child: Text('Answer 3'), onPressed: _ansQ)
             ]
```